# couldn't be able to add section header on multiple positions in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am having trouble with my code of putting a section header in my listview on more than one position.

this is my code,

to tell the adapter there are two types,

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == MainClass.addHeader) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

my `getView` method for the adapter,

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (position == MainClass.addHeader) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.heads, null);
        }

    } else {
        // Normal views are handled by the adapter
        convertView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Now the problem is that, the value of static variable `MainClass.addHeader` is initially `0` so the section header shows at position `0` , and that is correct.
But as I scroll through the list view the value of `MainClass.addHeader` changes several times , each time the value of `MainClass.addHeader` is changed, the section header is added on that position. but the problem is that the section header is disappeared from the previous positions when appear on new position.

for example,

initially, the value of `MainClass.addHeader` is `0` and section header appears at that position.

I scrolls down, the value of `MainClass.addHeader` change to `8` , the section header appears at that position but disappears from `0` position and onwards.

How to make my section header not to disappear from previous positions ?

Answer (score 0):

The header is ALWAYS at position 0.  If you want to add a different element to other places in your list, you should just make a custom adapter, and adjust that particular element that way.

Bottom line, the header is designed to remain at the top of your list (you could use a footer for the bottom), and is not designed to be inserted into the middle of a list.  You are trying to use it incorrectly.

If you are looking for a "Sticky Header" - ie. something that always remains on the screen, even when you scroll the list, you should create a unique view, and place it above your ListView in your layout.  You shouldn't use a list header for this, as it is specifically designed to scroll WITH the list.

Comment: thats not an actual header, its a custom xml and i am just calling it a header. You misunderstood my question. I am just trying to inflate custom xml on those positions.

Comment: hey booger can you check this question please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28294677/checking-internet-access-in-android it just needs and if else statement

Comment: Inflate your XML outside of your List, and it will not scoll (added this to my answer).

Comment: Agree with Mike for inflating XML outside of your list. And @bhuvesh do you know about sticky header?

Comment: @bhuvesh then you should! You would get tutorials and examples of the same, just try out the examples!